# Issue for a script - Hide/Show elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm working on a website, and i have a part which consist in hide/show elements when the user's clicking on a menu.

Here is the issue :

```js
$('[id^="answer"]').hide();

$('[class^="test"]').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var numb = this.className.replace('test', '');

  $('[id^="answer"]').hide();
  $('#answer' + numb).show();



});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    $('a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="test3" href="#">> test</a>

<div id="answer3">
     <div class="center">
       <p>hello</p>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think the PHP is irrelevant. Can you submit a fiddle or pen? Not sure if I fully understand your issue but it seems to work https://jsfiddle.net/a79e8wf4/

Comment: What I think, is going wrong, is that you're also hiding the ID's so jQuery doesn't know what to make of it. So then it won't be displayed again. Atleast, so far I've seen the code.

Comment: So try hiding the content, inside the `<div id="#">` and not the `<div id="#">` itself

Comment: Hey @Gezzasa , i was doing a fiddle, and it seems to work too.. Maybe there is a conflict in the import of library of Jquery ?

Comment: @Clément Do you get any errors in the browser console? Cause it works the first time you say so I'm guessing the lib imports correctly.

Comment: Look at my edit @Gezzasa

Comment: I'm a bit confused now. Will you update the edit with the whole script? Not sure where that one falls in to place. I also don't think you need to use an `a` for the button

Comment: @Gezzasa here we go, in my fiddle i reproduce the error.

Comment: When you add `active` class to `<a>` element, the class list changes to `"text3 active"`. So `this.className.replace('test', '');` return `"3 active"` and not `3`. therefore `$('#answer' + numb)` can not find any element,

Comment: @KavianK. Indeed. use data attributes instead of classes

Comment: Oh, ok @KavianK., so i have to replace the line "this.className ..." ?

Comment: @Gezzasa I'm beginning in jQuery, so that i have to replace the line this.className.replace by another thing ?

Comment: You can use this: `var str = this.className; var index = +str.indexOf( 'test' ) + 4; var numb = str.slice( index, index + 1);`

Comment: Thanks to you kavian, and gezzasa, have a nice day.

Comment: Or simply `var numb = this.className.match(/\d+/)[0];

Answer (score 0):

I tried it in JSBin and could not reproduce the error:

```
<a class="test2" href="#">Test 2</a>
<a class="test3" href="#">Test 3</a>

<div id="answer2">
  Answer2
</div>

<div id="answer3">
  Answer3
</div>

<script>
  $('[id^="answer"]').hide();

  $('[class^="test"]').on('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

    var numb = this.className.replace('test', '');

        $('[id^="answer"]').hide();
        $('#answer' + numb).show();

  });
</script>
```

https://jsbin.com/kekidusogo/edit?html,console,output

Comment: Hi Andreas, look at my edit, i found a way, my issue is from another little script which consist in put the class "active" on button which is active

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're looking for ...

You had an issue with your `"active"` class. Once this class is appended to your `<a>` tag your `var numb = this.className.replace('test', '');` becomes `"3 active"`, which is not what you are looking for. You want it always to be `"3"` in this case, regardless of other classes. That's why I added a loop to **check only for the `"test*"` class**:

```js
$('[id^="answer"]').hide();

$('[class^="test"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var classes = this.className.split(" ");
    var length = classes.length;
    var numb;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < length; i++){
     if (classes[i].indexOf('test') < 0) break;
     numb = classes[i].replace('test', '');
    }

    $('#answer' + numb).toggle();

});


$(document).ready(function(){
  $('a').click(function(){
    $('a').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");

});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="test3" href="#">> test</a>

<div id="answer3">
     <div class="center">
       <p>hello</p>
     </div>
</div>
```